# Only Displaying Results from NETWORKDAYS formula if both dates are entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like the "NETWORKDAYS" formula to show a solution only if the two cells that I am pulling from to determine the net working days are filled with dates.

My current formula is `=NETWORKDAYS(D3,T3)`.

If either *D3* or *T3* are not filled in with a date, then the result shows **#VALUE!**

I want it to not show anything in the cell where the formula is entered if either *D3* or *T3* are blank.

Comment: Can D3 and T3 be numbers or always Dates or empty

Comment: This is standard behavior for Excel. There are ways to hide it, but just so you're aware, you are supposed to see #value, or #div, or any of several other messages if the formula is missing information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide the #DIV/0! error while a referenced cell is blank?](https://superuser.com/questions/980470/how-do-i-hide-the-div-0-error-while-a-referenced-cell-is-blank)

Comment: While the linked question mentions #DIV errors, the answer covers all of these messages and is a good answer that will likely solve your problem. If it does not, come back here and edit your questions making sure to specify HOW it is different.

Answer (score 1):

If D3 and T3 are always Dates or empty you can use the following:

`=IF(OR(D3="",T3=""),"",NETWORKDAYS(D3,T3))`

Or will return `True` if any of D3 and T3 is empty
If will return "" if Or is `True`
Else your formula will give result

Just in case you might have `Text`  in D3 or T3
`=IF(OR(D3="",T3="",Istext(D3),Istext(T3)),"",NETWORKDAYS(D3,T3))`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make all error messages go away in the event of inappropriate inputs, you could use this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(NETWORKDAYS(D3, T3)), "", NETWORKDAYS(D3, T3))
```